# Include additional main effect if confounded with main effect of interest?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, main-effects

We tested the preference of animals for two treatments (A/B), with the prediction that the animals would spend a different amount time receiving each treatment. The treatments were applied by two experimenters (1/2) standing in two corners of the enclosure (r/l). To facilitate learning which treatment to expect, each experimenter always applied the same treatment in the same corner within the same animal, but corner and experimenter were balanced across animals. For example, the first animal would experience treatment A by experimenter 1 in corner r and treatment B by experimenter 2 in corner l. For the next animal, it would be treatment A by exp 2 in corner r and treatment B by exp 1 in corner l; and so on, also switching corners. After the training phase, we did two test sessions per animal (day 1/2). 
Our initial linear mixed model was `prop ~ treat * exp * day + corner  + (1|subject)`, with prop being the proportion of time the animal chose to spend receiving the treatment. We had included the experimenter in the interaction because there might be slight differences between the handlers that might affect the animals' overall preference for a treatment. After looking at the estimated means of the model, it became clear that the model was most likely mis-specified - it appears like the model assumed that the animal had the choice between the two treatments within each experimenter, which was not the case. 
I'm now wondering whether it makes more sense to have A) treat * day and exp * day in the model, or B) only treat * day. We are not interested in the effect of the experimenter, and I don't see how a main effect of the experimenter would influence our results for the main effect of treatment if the experimenter was balanced across animals - but it might still affect our dependent variable, the proportion of time spent with each treatment. 
The same goes for the corner - we had not included it in the interaction because there is no reasonable assumption about the corner influencing the perception of the treatment, but if model B) would be the (more) correct choice, that would mean that we should remove corner from the model as well. And if it is model A), should corner be in an interaction with day? Because the effect of corner might theoretically differ between days? 
I am leaning towards model A), but maybe one of the knowledgeable people here has a more well-founded opinion and could possibly provide some explanation for it?

Edit: I added an example dataset:

[image: Example dataset]

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! It would be helpful if you could post a small example dataset with the same structure as your actual dataset, and your outputs. Also, how many observations you have per animal? Only two?

Comment: @Sointu: I have two observations per animal (from two testing days).

Comment: OK! Sorry, I don't have time to answer properly now, hope someone else chips in, but just quickly: (1) in your example data it looks like you have 4 observations per animal (2 per day for 2 days)? (2) it seems to me random effect of "subject" (animal) captures exactly the same variance as exp*corner interaction, so both terms can't be in the model. In any case I'm sure you have too many/overlapping terms in the model. If you truly have 4 obs per animal I'd try prop ~ (1|subject)+(1|exp)+(1|corner)+treat x day (again, this was my quick intuition, hope you get more advice!)

Comment: The above would give you day x treatment fixed interaction while controlling for experimenter, corner and animal random effects.

Comment: @Sointu: Thank you for looking into this! (1) That depends on how you define observation. We have 4 data points per animal because we observed the duration of treatment A and the duration of treatment B on both days 1 and 2. But the two durations were recorded during the same observation. Strictly speaking there is some level of dependency between the two durations, because both treatments cannot happen at the same time, but the animals did not choose any treatment for a substantial amount of time, so this should not be a problem in practice.

Comment: @Sointu: I'd love to put the experimenter and the corner into the random effects, because I am not interested in their results, but they have only two levels each, which makes the model's calculation of the variability in the population very unreliable (I think a minimum of 5 levels is recommended). In addition, the corners are not really a random samples of all possible corners, which is also a prerequisite for considering a random effect, as far as I know...